# Does the TeamCity build feature "Pull request" automatically run a merge build?

Tags: teamcity

Does the TeamCity build feature `Pull request` automatically build a pull request against master? I'm not talking about merging automatically into master just building against it.

I can't seem to find any documentation. Previously in TC I could see two kinds of branches `33/merge` and `pull/33`, with the build feature enabled I can only see `pull/xx` being triggered. In the build summary it does state `Submitted into refs/heads/master, from xxxx-pull-request by xxxxxx`

So I can only assume it is running the pull request against `master` based on the text above, however I can't seem to find any documentation to indicate this.

Answer (score 0):

It is not automatic, it depends how vcs root is set
To build PR revision merge with current master set VCS root +:refs/pull/(*/merge)

See https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2013/02/automatically-building-pull-requests-from-github-with-teamcity/